# Pymongo find_and_modify - using slice

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to use find_and_modify in pymongo (to which I am very new)

the following syntax seems to fail with pymongo.errors.OperationFailure
can someone explain why

```
posts.find_and_modify(query={'permalink':permalink,'comments':{'$slice':[ordinal,1]}},update={'$inc':{'num_likes':1}},upsert=True)
```

posts is a valid collection and permalink an appropriate string , ordinal an int

Comment: This is for final exercises in M101 course. Isn't it? I'll noy give you the answer but I recommend you not to use slice to reslove it. ({'comments.2.data'} selects an item in comments array ;-) for update operations)

Comment: @francdaval - thanks - yes in the end I did use that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option

```
'$slice':[ordinal,1]
```

can not be part of query criteria, because it defines the return behavior. But by definition, find_and_modify function only deal with one search record. In your case, It's better to assign an id to each comment record and use 'commentId':ordinal as one criterion in query.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/ and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/ for reference.